# Scheduler logs different between airflow1 and airflow2

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

Because I can't use the airflow CLI, I'm actually parsing scheduler logs with grep on airflow**1** in order to retrieve some infos such as :

- check if the dag is triggered or not / if it's successful or not / start timestamp with the pattern "INFO Marking run" :

**[2021-12-01 11:06:50,340]** {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2021-12-01 11:06:50,339] {dagrun.py:307} INFO - Marking run <DagRun prd_*** @ 2021-12-01 10:02:00+00:00: scheduled__2021-12-01T10:02:00+00:00, **externally triggered: False>successful**

- when the dag is not triggered, I use the pattern 'INFO - Created' to retrieve the dag' start timestamp :

[2021-12-01 11:04:49,213] {scheduler_job.py:1298} INFO - Created <DagRun prd_*** @ 2021-12-01T10:02:00+00:00: scheduled__2021-12-01T10:02:00+00:00, externally triggered: False>

It works well on airflow1 but I can't find those data in the airflow**2** scheduler logs after migration.

Does the configuration need to be changed ?

Regards,
Troubadour

Answer (score 0):

You should use Airflow 2 REST API instead.

It was precisely done so that you do not have to parse logs. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html